# 'I got a cold' versus 'I caught a cold'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, american-english, british-english

The questions here are not about meaning.
They are about the usage of the verbs **get** and **catch** in the context of getting a cold.

[My dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get) says that **get** can be used to mean 'to become infected with an illness; to suffer from a pain, etc.' and gives the example:

> I **got** this cold off you.

My grammar confirms the dictionary and talks about **get a cold** in the chapter dedicated to the verb get. It also brings **catch a cold** to exemplify English collocations.

However, I was browsing the Internet and it seems that, at least for Americans, if we say **I got a cold** it is kind of uneducated. I **caught a cold** is what we should say.

1) Is this true? Is it better to say **I caught a cold** than **I got a cold**?
2) If it is the case, does this apply to British English as well?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"**Catch cold**" is the canonical form in the US and Commonwealth countries.

"**Get cold**" means something quite different, though the argument can easily be made that if you *get* cold you may well *catch* cold too.

Both expressions are idiomatic, since there're no transitive acts involved.  In neither case is "cold" a noun in these constructions.  It's a condition, the result of a process, thus (I think) an adverb.

In "catch **a** cold", cold is clearly a noun and "catch" again an idiomatic use of the verb.  There's an implication that the cold is "going around" or "making the rounds", and the catching was sheer accident.  It's sometimes cast the other way 'round for humorous purposes ("a cold caught me last week and hung on like grim death").

"Get a cold" isn't idiomatic since the noun "cold" in this context has been naturalised in English to mean a certain type of usually-minor-but-very-unpleasant-and-socially-offputting illness.  "Get a cold" is just raw information ("I got/had/suffered from a cold last week"; "I think you're getting/coming down with a cold").  To assign responsibility, explicit [and nearly always only mock-serious] complaint is needed:  "I think I got/have/caught your damned cold--thanks a lot!"

Comment: I like your answer, but I do not believe your first statement is correct, at least with regards to American usage. **"Catching a cold"** would be fine, but I've never heard anyone say "Catch cold."

Comment: Perhaps I'm out-of-date, but I heard it all the time growing up (we lived for years in Minnesota).  "You sound pretty bad, you gunna die [said jokingly]?" "Nah, I caught cold shoveling out some guy from DC whose car got stuck.  I should've put on a coat."

Comment: OK, good to know. *Fargo* much? :-)

Comment: @MarkHubbard Also "Be careful you don't catch cold." is also common. (AmE)

Answer (score 16):

In my experience (AmE), the proper form is *caught*.

> I **caught** a cold.

Using *got* is more informal, and can be used to indicate motion of the illness (as in your example):

> I **got** the cold from you.

But really I don't think there is much real difference.

Answer (score 3):

> I got a cold. *(AmE)*
>   I caught a cold.  *(BrE, AmE)*

both have the same meaning as

> I have a cold. *(BrE, AmE)*

that is that you are now sick.

"Caught" can leave the listener wondering "what" or "where" you acquired your illness. It also sounds more "active", as in you did something which contributed to you becoming ill

> I was outside shoveling the snow and **caught** a cold.
>   It's cold outside, bundle up or you will **catch** a cold!

Using "got" and "have" can be simply statements of a current condition, they are more "inactive"

> I was sitting on the couch all day and **got** a cold.
>   I stayed indoors, and now I **have** a cold.

There is a joke in the programming community

> I've got a code in my node.
>   *I've got a cold in my nose*
>   *(as said with a blocked nose)*

"I got a cold" is sometimes said as "I gotta cold" which may sound less educated or of a certain region, whereas

> I've got a cold.

is often used and more correct.

All these statements may be interchangeable with additional context.

Answer (score 2):

As a American from public education that stopped in high school, I would say "I *have* a cold".

Also "I caught a cold"  would to me mean that your cold recently happened.
And "I got a cold" is not necessarily uneducated you could say lazy or more accurately its slang way to say "I have a cold". Finally to me "I got a cold" means you have been feeling the symptoms of a cold for a prolonged period.