# When person is ill because of cold, then he "caught cold" or "got cold"?

Tags: phrase-usage

When a person is ill because of cold, then we can say about him that

> "He **caught** cold"

(in 1st p.: "I caught cold" or in modal "you can catch cold if you will not dress properly")

or

> "He **got** cold"?

(in 1st p.: "I got cold" or in modal "you can get cold if you will not dress properly")

Normally I've used "got cold" but someone wrote me that she caught cold (she's not Native English speaker) and that's what brought me to ask my question here.

In addition, I would love to know about the usage of these phrases or corresponding phrases in in the main English speaking countries such as: US, Britain, Canada and Australia (AmE, BrE, CaE, AuE).

Comment: Hi Industrious - I think this is a well-written question, but we have an older version of it that already has some answers. If you don't find them helpful, let's either put a bounty on it to get some more attention brought to it (let me know if you would like that,  I have some reputation to spare for it), or work on editing your question to make it different.

Comment: First of all thank you for your warmhearted comment. I am with your opinion, whatever it is (therefore feel free to use any of my reputation for it). By the way I saw this question there and it was difficult for me to follow it. If you didn't tell me that he asked my question, probably I wouldn't notice that it's the same question. Yes, I do think that there are place to talk about the acceptable phrases in different English speaking countries (mainly: AmE, BrE, CaE, AuE).

Comment: I think that is why it is important to link questions that have the same answer together. The way that you've written the question is easy to understand, so if someone finds this question, they will know that the answers on the linked question should help explain it. I will put a bounty on the other question to see if we can get some more comprehensive answers.

Comment: @Industrious: I can't see any mention on the original question about the fact that idiomatically [*You'll catch cold*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you%27ll+catch+cold%2Cyou%27ll+catch+a+cold&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20%27ll%20catch%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20%27ll%20catch%20a%20cold%3B%2Cc0) (no article) is still far more common than *You'll catch **a** cold*. That's a "set phrase", but it's definitely *not* the case in other contexts (*He caught **a** cold* is much more common than *He caught cold*, for example).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I totally missed the omission of the article - I'll reopen.

Comment: @ColleenV♦: Me and my big mouth! (or should I say *fat fingers?*). I suppose that means the onus is now on me to go over that distinction in an actual answer! :(

Comment: In the meantime found on the following definition: "**catch /take cold**, to get or suffer from a cold ("We all caught cold during that dreadful winter.").http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cold and in another dictionary I found this thing: "**take cold**
To become ill with the common cold. I hate going to the doctor's office—I always seem to take cold after being around all those germs!" from this dictionary: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+cold

Comment: NB "wear" is transitive (you wear clothes, you wear shoes, etc, but you don't just "\*wear"), so you can't say "\*...if you don't wear properly" - you want "if you don't *dress* properly".

Comment: You have suitable answers, but on local dialects, "caught cold" is relatively rare in AuE; "caught a cold" and "has/have a cold" are both fairly common.

Comment: I caught a cold == I am sick/ill ...
I got cold == I am freezing (but I may not be sick) ...

Answer (score 11):

To "get cold" means to have your body temperature (or at least your perception of it) become enough lower that you feel somewhat uncomfortable.  "Get/become cold" implies a lower temperature than "get/become chilly".

To "get **a** cold" means to become sick with a certain type of usually-minor illness, characterised by some or all of:  coughing, sneezing, runny nose, headache, sore throat, etc.  You can substitute either "catch cold" OR "catch **a** cold", the "catch" implying that it was accidental, whereas "get a cold" is just the raw information.

And the "if" part should be "...if you do not **dress** properly".  Dress in this case is a reflexive idiom meaning "clothe yourself", so you can substitute "...if you do not clothe yourself properly/suitably/appropriately" or "...if you do not wear the proper/suitable/appropriate clothing".

Comment: This does a good job addressing all the possible article/non-article permutations, and also the awkward "wear properly". I might add that the last bit could also be "if you will not *wear **your coat** properly*" (or whatever item of clothing isn't fastened or fully-on or what-have-you).

Answer (score 10):

As it happens, I watched the (British) movie [It Always Rains on Sunday (1947)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0040481/) last night, where I was struck by the fact that the warning ***You'll catch cold!*** occurred at least three times.

At the time, I never particularly noticed the fact that *there's no article* in that particular version (to me that's syntactically totally normal, but I think I know that [*Getting cold or wet won’t give you a cold*](http://www.nhs.uk/Livewell/coldsandflu/Pages/Preventionandcure.aspx)).

---

As [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you%27ll+catch+cold%2Cyou%27ll+catch+a+cold&year_start=1910&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20%27ll%20catch%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20%27ll%20catch%20a%20cold%3B%2Cc0) shows...

[image]

...we don't usually include the article in that *particular* "set phrase", but if we [look at other versions](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+caught+cold%2Che+caught+a+cold%2CI+caught+cold%2CI+caught+a+cold&year_start=1910&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20caught%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20caught%20a%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20caught%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20caught%20a%20cold%3B%2Cc0)...

[image]

...it's different. I can't see much of a US/UK usage split here, but there might be *some* suggestion that AmE has moved further towards standardising on *catch/caught **a** cold* in all contexts.

---

There's also [this related earlier ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68479/i-got-a-cold-versus-i-caught-a-cold), but it's primarily concerned with a (spurious) *semantic* distinction between *catch a cold* and *get a cold* (where the latter is distinct from *get cold*, which means *become cold by losing body heat*).

Comment: Brilliant as usual, FF. As a native speaker of American English, I don't recall ever hearing these phrases *without* the article. To my ear, "He got cold" simply means the subject became chilled, while "He got a cold" means the subject contracted the common-cold *virus*. Also, where is the link to the question/answer that ColleenV cited? Thank you.

Comment: As an AmE Speaker in the Midwest USA, If i heard "caught cold" (which I never have), I would think its an accent and they forgot the article A. There are only 2 kinds of Cold I know of, To be cold (feeling), and to have a Cold(virus). "Caught a Cold" and "Got a Cold" imply having a Cold (the virus) while "Got cold" implies just being cold. "Caught cold" makes no sense to me. Without the A, it implies the feeling and not the virus, but you cant catch a feeling.

Comment: Also native AmE speaker here, and I never noticed until now but I have heard the usage "to catch cold" but never (to my notice) "caught cold".  "Got cold" is a common phrase that has nothing to do with a virus, just temperature.

Comment: @MarkHubbard Just FYI, on the full site you can see suggested duplicates (past or present) and any other ELL questions that have been linked in the comments in the right sidebar under "LInked". The questions under "Related" are automated guesses.

Comment: I'm an American and was honestly confused by the question at first. I thought they were asking about getting sick due to *being* cold (as in chilly) rather than catching a cold (as in a virus). It could depend on the region, though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, your answer does not address the OP's question. He does not ask whether it is with or without "a", but if it is "got" or "caught".

Comment: @rexkogitans: This question was originally closed as a duplicate of the one I linked to as *this related earlier ELL question* above, which as I pointed out deals with a ***spurious*** possible distinction between using ***catch*** or ***get*** (to the extent that there *can* be a distinction, it primarily turns on whether the article is present or not).

Comment: @ColleenV - Thank you for your help! I'm so used to vendors following me around the internet with advertisements, that I have unconsciously stopped looking at sidebars. I recently purchased a gift for my wife on JTV.com, and now almost every page I open greets me with pictures of colored gemstones. It is ridiculous. Now that I know "Linked" and "Related" are there on ELL and EL&U, I'll be sure to use them. Thank you again for your kind assistance. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

There are some good answers already describing the finer points
of usage regarding "catch cold", "catch a cold", and "get cold".

But there is a lurking misunderstanding in the question:

> When someone is ill because of cold,

A native speaker would infer that exposure to low temperatures were part
of some set of circumstances that caused the person ("someone") to become ill. The nature of the illness itself is not specified;
the illness *could* be what we call "a cold" (caused by a virus),
it could be pneumonia (caused by a virus or bacterium and
usually much more serious than a cold), or it could be one of
several other illnesses.

Note that mere exposure to a virus, without exposure to cold temperatures,
can often cause someone to catch a cold.

I hope I am not belaboring the point too much, but I wanted it to be
clear that *neither* of your two proposed phrases ("caught cold"
or "got cold") truly means "became ill because of cold."
The phrase "caught cold" is neither a general way to describe an
illness caused by cold nor does it imply that cold temperatures
caused the illness, while the phrase "got cold" does not indicate an illness at all.

Comment: That's true: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_cold